# Are there circumstances when one should repeat a prayer in which he had no kavana the first time?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, mistakes, kavana-concentration

[Halichipedia](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Shemoneh_Esrei#cite_ref-54) writes

> One should have kavana (proper concentration) when praying Shemonah
>   Esrei. If one is unable to have kavana for all of Shemonah Esrei one
>   should make an extra effort to have kavana for the first Bracha (Magen
>   Avraham). If one didn’t have kavana even in the first Bracha according
>   to the strict law one is obligated to return to the beginning of
>   Shemonah Esrei. However, nowadays if one did not have kavana one
>   should not return to the beginning of Shemonah Esrei.

The footnote reads:

> The Tur 101:1 writes that nowadays if one didn’t have kavana in the
>   first Bracha of Shemonah Esrei one shouldn’t have to return to the
>   beginning because once one didn’t have kavana the first time there’s
>   no guarantee that one is going to be successful the next time. This is
>   the ruling of the Rama 101:1.

My question is:
Where there is a reason to think that the circumstances are that he **will be able to concentrate better the second time** (because whatever was disturbing him has stopped), is he permitted or even obliged to repeat if he did not have kavana in the first prayer?